# Detect Authentication timeout in RIA Services

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight application which makes use of RIA Services to communicate with the server and I am using membership API with Forms Authentication. The problem I am facing now is that the app throws exception when it tries to access the server via RIA after the original login has expired (authentication timeout). This is expected but the error doesn't say exactly what the problem is so that I can handle it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not exactly what you are asking for but I can approach it differently. http://bryantlikes.com/IdleTimeoutsInRIAServicesAuthentication.aspx http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/07/15/Forms-Authentication-Timeout.aspx

Comment: I have actually thought about approachig it the way you suggested. I just wanted to find out if there's a better way to do it. Thank you.